# using WKWebView plugin in Cordova project does not allow Keyboard to show on focus for iOS 13

Tags: cordova, wkwebview, ios13

I was using UIWebView before in my Cordova project and it used to show the keyboard on focus. Now as UIWebView is deprecated by Apple, I am using WKWebView instead. The Keyboard is not showing on focus for iOS13. The input box has to be tapped to get the Keyboard showing. Is there any other keyboard plugin which can be used with WKWebView? or What can be the solution to this?